# Не могу подключить bootstrap.js через webpacker

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, webpack

Не могу подключить bootstrap.js через webpacker.
Что сделано

```
yarn add bootstrap popper.js jquery
```

> app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

> config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

module.exports = environment
```

> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Но bootstrap.js не подгружается. Я хотел использовать modal. Все работает, если я добавлю в views

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Что неправильно делаю с webpack?

Comment: Сервер рестартовали?

Comment: Да, сервер рестартовал. Сейчас обнаружил, что webpack собирает bootstrap. При этом функция .modal все еще $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: Отлично. Все это можно починить при помощи куска кода в environment.js const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias = {
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отлично, все это исправляется добавлением в config/webpack/environment.js

```
const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias = {
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
}
```

Теперь config/webpack/environment.js выглядит как

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias = {
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
}

module.exports = environment;
```